# Don't allow A-Z and 0-9 number in textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation

I want to implement some validation in my project, validation is that: Don't allow number 0-9 and A-Z in `UITextField`, only allow GUJARATI letter in `UITextField`. I have tried some validation but It was not working. I need some help from anyone.

I have tried this below code:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    //limit the size :
    if([self checkValidation:textField] == true)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)checkValidation:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *rejex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"[A-Za-z0-9]"];
    NSPredicate *gujTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rejex];

    //if rejex fullfil than it will return true else false.
    return [gujTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text];
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For this problem it would be better to use a `CharacterSet` detection. Regular expression don't work very well with unicode. Also, it is better to check for characters your want to allow than the other way around:

```
let text = textField.text ?? ""
// https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0A80.pdf 0x0A80 ... 0x0AFF
let gurajatiCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: Unicode.Scalar(0x0A80 as Int)! ...  Unicode.Scalar(0x0AFF as Int)!)
return text.rangeOfCharacter(from: gurajatiCharacterSet.inverted) == nil
```

Objective-C:

```
NSUInteger minValue = 0x0A80;
NSUInteger maxValue = 0x0AFF;
NSCharacterSet *gurajatiCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange(minValue, maxValue - minValue + 1)];

return [textField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[gurajatiCharacterSet invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound;
```

Comment: @Satish I want to do this in OBJECTIVE-C

Comment: @MonikaPatel Uh oh, missed that :)

Comment: @MonikaPatel Added Obj-c version

Answer (score 0):

In your `checkValidation` function, you are taking `textField` as an argument and extracting its `text` property - but you call it in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, and by that point the `text` property still holds the old value of text, before the update (it gets updated after you return `true` from this function). Do instead

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    //limit the size :
    if([self checkValidation:string] == true)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)checkValidation:(NSString *)string
{
    let stringWithGujaratiCharacters = "અ" // string with all Gujarati letters
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: stringWithGujaratiCharacters).inverted // character set containing every character besides Gujarati letters
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil // returns true if string contains characters other than Gujarati letters
}
```

If you just don't want to allow latin alphanumeric characters, change your `characterSet`

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
```

Answer (score 0):

Change textfield to string on below code. it will work.

```
if([self checkValidation:string] == true)
```

and

```
- (BOOL)checkValidation:(NSString *)textField
{
    NSString *rejex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"[A-Za-z0-9]"];
    NSPredicate *gujTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rejex];

     //if rejex fullfil than it will return true else false.
    return [gujTest evaluateWithObject:textField];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this problem you can use NSCharacterSet.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```